# oracle 19c rac cluster nodes show in different time zones

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c, oracle-rac

working on an oracle 19c 2-node rac cluster.  we were running awr reports when we noted in `sys.dba_hist_snapshot` that the cluster nodes were in different time zones. We have validated that our `s_crsconfig` files on each server both show `America/Los_Angeles` as the time zone.  timedatectl also shows that the nodes are both in the same time zone (America/Los_Angeles / PST8PDT).

(1) How can I tell which time zone each node thinks it is in?
(2) How can I resolve this so that both nodes agree on the time zone?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check the actual value of TZ variable of database processes on both nodes, example:

> ```
> $ ps -ef | grep [o]ra_smon
> oracle   1296361       1  0 20:46 ?        00:00:00 ora_smon_KIRA1
> $ sudo strings /proc/1296361/environ | grep TZ
> TZ=Europe/Budapest
> $
> ```

2. Make sure it has the same value on both nodes. `s_crsconfig` was a good start, but `TZ` can be defined at DB resource level with `srvctl setenv` (check with `srvctl getenv database -db DB_UNIQUE_NAME`) or other custom locations if the instances were started with `sqlplus` instead of `srvctl`. If you can not find where it was set, you may try setting `TZ` with `srvctl setenv` which should take care of this on the next instance restart with `srvctl`, but normally this is unnecessary.